# Server-side Faye subscription in a cluster environment

Tags: node.js, publish-subscribe, faye

I have a cluster of nodejs-based Faye servers. The server itself needs to subscribe to a channel in order to perform a certain set of operations: to do so, I use the server's client as such:

```
var bayeux_server = new faye.NodeAdapter({
  mount:    '/pubsub',
  timeout:  25,
  engine: engine
});

//initialize the client
var client = bayeux_server.getClient();

var subscription = client.subscribe('/chat/*', function(message) {
  ///.....
});
```

This works fine as long as there is only one thread. But if I spawn a cluster, each thread will subscribe, and each subscription will trigger. How do I make sure that only one thread per time triggers the subscription action?